# Shaping magnetic fields to draw with iron filings?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Can you create a specific magnetic field which shapes iron filings to specific drawing ?

Comment: Like etch a sketch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show sufficient previous effort.

Answer (score 2):

The induced magnetic dipole moments make iron filings follow magnetic field lines. Therefore, the drawings one could obtain are limited by the properties of magnetic field lines:

1. lines cannot intersect each other (because it would result in a magnetic field having two directions at one point);
2. lines cannot start or end at one point but they have to be closed curves (consequence of the $\nabla \cdot {\bf B}=0$ condition).

Within these two fundamental bounds, it would be possible to obtain different shapes ofr the field lines by exploiting the superposition property of the field.  However, an additional practical constraint would be the presence of of a finite volume occupied by the sources of the field (permanent magnets or conductors carrying currents).

Although all these observations seem to greatly limit the possibility of drawing designs with iron filings, things are much better in practice due to the fact that magnetic field lines live in the $3$D space, while drawings have are $2$D.
Therefore, a clever exploiting of direction of magnetic fields, as well as the density of iron particles, allow a flourishing *iron filing art*.  For nice examples, look for "iron filings artists" on google.